# Error : The access token could not be decrypted

Tags: facebook, token

Since few days, when I try to use tokens to publish in wall of user from my application I have this error : `The access token could not be decrypted`

This is the first time I got this error and I really don't understand why.

The tokens generated in march still working (I use long lived access and publish_actions). So to be sure, I create some news tokens (from the same application) now, and they are currently post fine on wall. (maybe they will get the error soon? I don't know for the moment)

So why I have this error with the tokens generate this month (April), except tokens generate now (for test)?

Maybe Facebook has changed something this month in the code to post?

Comment: I think Facebook just changed the length of the Access Token which might have caused issue you are facing

Answer (score 6):

I had a similar issue and discovered that the reason was that our database only stored was limited to access tokens 200 characters or less so our access tokens were getting truncated. I widened the database field to 512 characters and things are working again for me. It seems access tokens are now 219 characters long.

Answer (score 1):

Yes It seems like Database field size issue.
Change the database field to save 512 characters or more.

In my case it works.